# softlayer get primary volume id given replica volume id

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working with SL Block volumes. volume with id '1' is being replicated to volume with id '2'. 
'slcli block volume-detail 1' also confirms this relationship

Now, I can get '2' given '1' using getReplicationPartners API.
But I haven't found a way to get '1' given '2'

getReplicationPartners(id=2) returns nothing.

getReplicatingVolume(id=2) returns < storageTypeId >3< /storageTypeId > and < nasType >NAS_CONTAINER< /nasType >. But the id is not '1'.

So how do I get primary volume id('1') when all I have is the id of the replica volume ('2')

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

e.g.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getReplicatingLuns

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$REPLICAID/getReplicatingLuns
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works.

A followup question - I see that I need to use two different APIs, getReplicationPartners / getReplicatingLuns depending on whether I am working with a primary volume id or replica volume id.
Is there a common API that would give me the *partner* regardless of whether the input is primary / replica volume id?
If not, should I be using *storageTypeId* to first find out if the input is primary / replica volume id, and then use specific API to get its partner?

Comment: nope there is not such method, you could use object mask to fetch the information of replicationPartners and ReplicatingLuns at once. e.g. https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/11167839/getObject?objectMask=mask[replicationPartners,replicatingLuns]    You could use the "nasType" property the replicas should end with the word "REPLICANT" and the primary storage do not have that word.